# Download files in synchronous manner and extract downloaded files asynchronously using C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a big list of URLs of some large zip files. I'm downloading files in a loop by using `HttpClient`. I have to extract the files after the download process. I want to start extracting each file as they finish downloading instead of waiting for the entire download process to complete. File download should happen in a synchronous manner(one by one) and the extraction should happen asynchronously with each downloaded file. My application is using .Net Framework 4.5.2 and C#7.

In the below code, the file download is also asynchronous. I'm trying to avoid asynchronous downloads because of bandwidth concerns.

```
public void DownloadAndExtract()
{
        IDataReader dr = _myDB.GetFileUrl();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
                DownloadFile(new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString())).ContinueWith(task1 =>
                {
                      var downloadedFilePath = task1.Result.fileName;
                      ExtractFile(downloadedFilePath).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                });
         }
         dr.Close();     
 }
```

Comment: The answer is yes. There are many ways to achieve this, however depending on your needs (which are very light on the details) This could easily be put in a DataFlow pipeline or Reactive Extensions (RX), or you could get creative with Tasks and SemaphoreSlim

Comment: Since there are no actual details or concrete example workflows (apart from a limited top level overview), its near impossible to write code that would be of any use to you

Comment: `File download should happen in a synchronous manner(one by one)` Why do you want it synchronous?

Comment: To meet your requirements as stated, one thread / task adding to a `BlockingCollection` and a second thread / task using `Parallel.ForEach` to process the `BlockingCollection` seems a reasonably straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) implementation. Two blocks are used, one [`TransformBlock<Uri, string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2) for downloading the URLs, and one [`ActionBlock<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1) for extracting the files.

```
private void DownloadAndExtract()
{
    var downloadBlock = new TransformBlock<Uri, string>(async uri =>
    {
        var downloadedFile = await DownloadFileAsync(uri);
        return downloadedFile.fileName;
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
    });

    var extractBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(async filePath =>
    {
        await ExtractFileAsync(filePath);
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded
    });

    downloadBlock.LinkTo(extractBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });

    IDataReader dr = _myDB.GetFileUrl();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        downloadBlock.Post(new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString()));
    }
    dr.Close();
    downloadBlock.Complete();
    extractBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
```

Storing all `Uri`s in a list before posting them to the `downloadBlock` would be safer. With the code above a single malformed `URL` in the database will cause the `DownloadAndExtract` method to fail, while the previous URLs are downloaded and extracted in the background, in a fire and forget fashion.

---

**Note:** I added the `Async` suffix to the asynchronous methods `DownloadFile` and `ExtractFile`, to comply with the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types).

Comment: Here I want to pass a FileCategory to ExtractFileAsync method. FileCategory is in the database. How can I pass dr["FileCategory"] to ExtractFileAsync  method?

Comment: @rinesh if you have more data that you want to pass from block to block, probably the easiest way to do it is to create a class that has properties with all the data needed for processing a URL, as well as properties for data that will be obtained along the way. Then, assuming that the class name is `UrlData`, you can change the type of the blocks in the dataflow pipeline like this: `TransformBlock<UrlData, UrlData>` and `ActionBlock<UrlData>`. Then you'll feed the pipeline with instances of this class: `downloadBlock.Post(new UrlData() { Uri: new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString()) });`

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd simplify my life:

```
public async Task DownloadAndExtractAsync()
{
    using(IDataReader dr = _myDB.GetFileUrl()){
        while (dr.Read())
        {
          var f = await DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString()));
          _ = ExtractFileAsync(f.fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that perturbs me about this is that it potentially holds the db connection open for an unreasonably long time.. Perhaps:

```
public async Task DownloadAndExtractAsync()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(IDataReader dr = _myDB.GetFileUrl())
       dt.Load(dr);

    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        var f = await DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(dr["URL"].ToString()));
        _ = ExtractFileAsync(f.fileName);
    }
}
```

Suffixing (with `...Async`) your methods that behave in an asyncronous way would benefit people who have to read the code, especially people on the internets who don't have the benefit of intellisense/definition of your called methods

Comment: After the extraction of all files completed, I have to perform some other operations. How to know all extraction task is completed in this code?

Comment: Put a ExtractFileAsync.ContinueWith in? Put the operations as part of the extract? There is very little detail present on your requirement

Comment: Next operations should start only after all files extracted(not after each file extracted). So it cannot be done as part of the extract. How to wait for all ExtractFileAsync to be completed?

Comment: Ah, in that case rather than discarding you'd probably want to collect them into some kind of list and use Task.WhenAll on it.. I guess it stands to reason that because you want to wait for download before extract, and probably that extract is faster, it could be as simple as doing your downloads and extract adds in the loop, then using an await WhenAll outside it, then continuing. One thing I'd be wary of perhaps is too much simultaneous extracting could really batter the IO side of things; hopefully you've got at least SSDs!